# Ошибка в коде python: IndentationError: expected an indented block (помогите пожалуйста)

Tags: python

Мой код

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((441,441))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
flag_game = True
head = [45,45]
var_speed = 0

while flag_game:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
   window.fill(pygame.Color("Black"))
   pygame.draw.rect(window,pygame.Color("Green"),pygame.Rect(head[0],head[1],10,10))
   if var_speed % 1000 == 0:
       head[0] += 25
   var_speed += 1
   pygame.display.flip()
```

Ошибка в 13 строчке

```
File "D:/GAMES_2/Snake/main.py", line 13
   window.fill(pygame.Color("Black"))
   ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Отступы в Python имеют значение. Это написано на первых страницах любого учебника.

Answer (score 1):

В условии `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:` нет действия. Вам нужно либо написать туда что-то, либо удалить условие